# Email forwarding in PHP

Tags: php, email

My following code is tested by my friends. They said its working fine. But I am unable to use it. Can anybody find where the error is.

`

```
<?php
  try
  {
  // Change to your mail server
  $host = "pop.gmail.com";

  // Connecting to POP3 email server.
  $connection = imap_open("{" . $host . ":995/pop3/notls}", 'someusername@gmail.com', 'somepassword');

  // Total number of messages in Inbox
  $count = imap_num_msg($connection);
  echo $count . " messages found<br />";

  // Read Messages in Loop, Forward it to Actual User email and than delete it from current email account.
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
      $headers = imap_headerinfo($connection, $i);

      $subject = $headers->subject;

      $from = $headers->from[0]->mailbox . '@' . $headers->from[0]->host;
      if ($headers->cc[0]->mailbox)
          $cc = $headers->cc[0]->mailbox . '@' . $headers->cc[0]->host;
      $subject = $headers->subject;

      $structure = imap_fetchstructure($connection, $i);
      $type = $this->get_mime_type($structure);

      // GET HTML BODY
      $body = $this->get_part($connection, $i, "");

      //$raw_body = imap_body($connection, $i);

      $attachments = array();

      if (isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {
          for ($e = 0; $e < count($structure->parts); $e++) {
              $attachments[$e] = array('is_attachment' => false, 'filename' => '', 'name' => '', 'attachment' => '');

              if ($structure->parts[$e]->ifdparameters) {
                  foreach ($structure->parts[$e]->dparameters as $object) {
                      if (strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                          $attachments[$e]['is_attachment'] = true;
                          $attachments[$e]['filename'] = $object->value;
                      } //if (strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename')
                  } //foreach ($structure->parts[$e]->dparameters as $object)
              } //if ($structure->parts[$e]->ifdparameters)

              if ($structure->parts[$e]->ifparameters) {
                  foreach ($structure->parts[$e]->parameters as $object) {
                      if (strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                          $attachments[$e]['is_attachment'] = true;
                          $attachments[$e]['name'] = $object->value;
                      } //if (strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name')
                  } //foreach ($structure->parts[$e]->parameters as $object)
              } //if ($structure->parts[$e]->ifparameters)

              if ($attachments[$e]['is_attachment']) {
                  $attachments[$e]['attachment'] = @imap_fetchbody($connection, $i, $e + 1);
                  if ($structure->parts[$e]->encoding == 3) {
                      // 3 = BASE64
                      $attachments[$e]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$e]['attachment']);
                  } //if ($structure->parts[$e]->encoding == 3)
                  elseif ($structure->parts[$e]->encoding == 4) {
                      // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
                      $attachments[$e]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$e]['attachment']);
                  } //elseif ($structure->parts[$e]->encoding == 4)
              } //if ($attachments[$e]['is_attachment'])

              if ($attachments[$e]['is_attachment']) {
                  $filename = $attachments[$e]['filename'];
                  $filename = $attachments[$e]['name'];
                  $filecontent = $attachments[$e]['attachment'];
              } //if ($attachments[$e]['is_attachment'])
          } //for ($e = 0; $e < count($structure->parts); $e++)
      } //if (isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts))
      /**** ****/


      /*echo "<pre>";
      echo "From: " . $headers->Unseen . "<br />";
      echo "From: " . $from . "<br />";
      echo "Cc: " . $cc . "<br />";
      echo "Subject: " . $subject . "<br />";
      echo "Content Type: " . $type . "<br />";
      echo "Body: " . $body . "<br />";*/
      $mail = new Zend_Mail();

      $mail->settype(Zend_Mime::MULTIPART_MIXED);

      for ($k = 0; $k < count($attachments); $k++) {
          $filename = $attachments[$k]['name'];
          $filecontent = $attachments[$k]['attachment'];

          if ($filename && $filecontent) {
              $file = $mail->createAttachment($filecontent);
              $file->filename = $filename;
          } //if ($filename && $filecontent)
      } //for ($k = 0; $k < count($attachments); $k++)


      $mail->setFrom($from);
      $mail->addTo('testmail@softmail.me');
      if ($cc)
          $mail->addCc($cc);
      $mail->setSubject($subject);
      $mail->setBodyHtml($body);
      $mail->send();

      // Mark the email messages once read
      //imap_delete($mbox, 1);
  } //for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++)
  // Delete all marked message from current email account.

  imap_expunge($mbox);
  echo 'If you see this, the number is 1 or below';
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

Comment: @Maerlyn - No error its displaying all messages in echo. But not working

Comment: If you use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before the `try` block to enable error reporting, are there still no error messages? http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Comment: In which environment occurs this error? Is IMAP support in your php installation enabled? Have a look at `phpinfo()`

Comment: Did you get this working?  If so, can you add your working code as an answer?  FWIW, the use of `$this` outside a class seems odd

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have enabled

```
extension=php_openssl.dll;
```

ext in you php.ini. I had faced this problem once and enabling the above extension worked for me.